# Bulk read ResultSet?

Tags: performance, jdbc, resultset

I'm having problems iterating through ResultSet with 10,000 to 25,000 entries. It takes 1.5 seconds to run through this loop:

```
while(rs.next()){
  // totally empty loop
}
```

In another question, several suggested experimenting with different fetchsizes. Trying out 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000 only reduced iteration time from 1.5s to 1.4s on average.

Is there a way to bulk read or use multithreading or concurrency to speed up this iteration?

Comment: How fast are you expecting the iteration to happen? What is your application? 1ms per entry doesn't sound that bad, in general.

Comment: Also, the iteration time could easily pale in comparison to the processing time if the code in the loop does anything non-trivial.

Comment: In general, result set iteration time depends heavily on how the JDBC driver is implemented. Some will retrieve data up front, but then read from cache so the first fetch is long, and others up to a point are essentially immediate. Some have other retrieval mechanisms, if you're having trouble with a specific driver perhaps there's another that will also work for that data source?